# How to introduce individual version of docker container in ansible script?

Tags: docker, ansible

Let suppose  4 docker containers are running. they have there respective versions. Now I want to introduce these individual version in ansible script. Each version need to be declared in group_vars (with leatest by default)
so how can I do that ? appreciated if you reply to this post

Answer (score 1):

Containers themselves can be referred to by their [container names](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#assign-name-and-allocate-pseudo-tty-name-it), plain and simple. You can add whatever you want to the name within the limitations of container names, e.g. `docker run -d --name="webapp-container-1462574616" milind/webapp:0.0.10` or whatever, and then that is how you would refer to that specific container anywhere else. For example `docker stop webapp-container-1462574616`. You refer to *images* via the version in the image tag, e.g. `milind/webapp:0.0.10`.